# When is the Thread Pool created?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, multithreading

I am working on a problem in my WPF application which uses the ASP.NET Membership & Role providers for SQL Anywhere.  The app uses `BackgroundWorker` objects to perform tasks in the background off of the UI thread.  In a nutshell:

1. During program start-up, the application allows the user to log in.
2. Once the user has logged in, it creates an instance of a custom `User` class.  This class implements the `IPrincipal` interface.
3. Once the instance of the custom `User` class is created, it is passed to the `AppDomain.SetThreadPrincipal` method so that every new `Thread` that is created uses it as the default `Principal`.
4. The background tasks use the `Thread.CurrentThread.Principal` property to determine the name of the user currently logged in and retrieve the user's permissions from the `Role` provider.

This mechanism has worked fine for 3 years, but something changed recently.  We have upgraded a number of third-party libraries and now, the `BackgroundWorker` threads are using the default `Principal`, which has the empty string as the user name.  This means that no data is retrieved from the database when the roles checks are performed and the background tasks don't work.

So it seems that the threads in the thread pool are being created sooner than they used to be before the recent upgrades.  I'd like to find out when they're being created so I can investigate the possibility of performing the user log-in process earlier in the start-up.

Just when does .NET create the thread pool and the threads inside of it?

Comment: .Net thread pool being a static access, loads as soon as CLR loads in the process (mscoree.dll), it has always been like that, in fact this is for all CLR instances machine wide. In this case issue that you may want to debug is what happens when BackgroundWorker access the Membership APIs to fetch the username, most likely issue would be out there. You may want to add some logging to figure out what happens when Membership APIs are accessed.

Comment: The thread pool is created at program startup. A few pool threads are created at startup, but others are created on demand, as needed. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

While I can't confirm exactly when the Thread Pool is started, I can confirm that it is available from the `Application.Startup` event, which is the very first event that is raised in a WPF Application. This is easily testable.. add a handler for this event in `App.xaml` and run a `Task` from it:

```
<Application x:Class="Midas.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Startup="App_Startup">
    ...
</Application>
```

...

```
public void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Task startupTask = new Task(() => SomeMethod());
}
```

If the call to `SomeMethod` works, then the Thread Pool is working, because the `Task` library uses it under the covers. From [The Managed Thread Pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN:

> Beginning with the .NET Framework 4, the easiest way to use the thread pool is to use the Task Parallel Library (TPL). By default, parallel library types like Task and Task use thread pool threads to run tasks.

Comment: So it seems that the thread pool is available to use as soon as your program is loaded.  That's fine.  But when does it create the threads that make it up?  If its as soon as the thread pool class is loaded by the CLR, then why is it that the same code, before the recent upgrades, had the correct principal in the `Tread.CurrentPrincipal` property, but don't after the upgrade?

Comment: @TonyVitabile It creates them as needed. If the ThreadPool is full of work for a long enough time, it's going to create new threads, very slowly. The original bunch (`ThreadPool.MinXXXThreads`) is created with the thread pool itself.

Comment: @Luaan: I managed to put a trace point on the `Thread.SetCurrentPrincipal` method and discovered that there are indeed a number of threads that are created when the program starts with the `GenericPrincipal' as the parameter before my code sets the AppDomain's Thread Principal.  I can't tell where that call is made from, however, as it is called from a native-to-managed transition (the only thing on the call stack is the call to that method).  I need to look at fixing this at the time the AppDomain's Thread Principal is set to my principal; changing the init order may not always work.

Comment: @TonyVitabile Or you could just pass the principal of the UI thread to the background worker ;)